# Determine which disease cluster together

Tags: statistics, sas, bioinformatics

How do I determine which diseases cluster together? I have a dataset with patients and their diseases. It's coded as HOHT = 1 if they have it, and HOHT = 0 if they do not have it.

Below is an example of the data. How would I go about determining which diseases occur most often with each other without writing a bunch of if then statements? The goal is to create something like a Venn diagram or a dendogram showing the overlapping of diseases.

```
Moya    Hypothyroid Hyperthyroid    Celiac
   1       1           0             0
   1       1           0             0       
   0       0           1             1
   0       0           0             0
   1       1           0             0
   1       0           1             0
   1       1           0             0
   1       1           0             0
   0       0           1             1
   0       0           1             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of would be to have a look at the correlation matrix via `proc corr`:

```
data diseases;
input Moya    Hypothyroid Hyperthyroid    Celiac;
cards;
   1       1           0             0
   1       1           0             0       
   0       0           1             1
   0       0           0             0
   1       1           0             0
   1       0           1             0
   1       1           0             0
   1       1           0             0
   0       0           1             1
   0       0           1             1
  ; 
run;

proc corr data = diseases out = disease_corr; run;
```

There are various other options, but I'm not sure whether this question is really the best fit for this site as it's very broad and more about statistics than programming. If you run into a more specific problem feel free to ask another question.